# how to call other method on karma unittest?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Suppose I have a service like this:

```
app.factory('dataService', function () {
    return {
        getData: function (item) {
          var item = addClaimItem(item)  ;
          return true;
        },

        addClaimItem: function (item) {
            return false;
        }
}}
```

My test looks like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){

        inject(function (_dataService_) {
                dataService = _dataService_;
            }
        );


   dataService.addClaimItem = jasmine.createSpy('dataService').and.returnValue(true)


});

it('should find it',function(){
    expect(dataService.getData({})).toBe(false);
});
```

Getting an error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.addClaimitem(

How can I mock out or fix this test where I am calling another method on the same service?

Comment: You shouldn't be mocking anything of the component that you're testing. Remove the line with `dataService.addClaimItem = jasmine.createSpy(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I could think to test is that `getData` called through to `addClaimItem`. To test that, you can [spy on](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Spies) `addClaimItem`. For example

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_dataService_) {
    dataService = _dataService_;
}));

it('getData calls through to addClaimItem', function() {
    spyOn(dataService, 'addClaimItem');

    var obj = {};

    expect(dataService.getData(obj)).toEqual(true); // it returns true, not false
    expect(dataService.addClaimItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj);        
});
```